# Spring3 - using Views from parent project- getting 404

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc

I have a parent "base" project (jar) which contains controllers with their corresponding views.

In my child project (war), I have a dependency on this parent project in my pom.xml and "import" the parents application context in the childs application context, however when I start the web app, I get a 404 on /views/index.jsp.

How am i able to get my child war project to know about the parents views, the controllers are all working as expected with the use of annotations.

I get a 404 on /views/index.jsp, i guess this is because its looking in my child project (war) for the views, where as they are in the parent project...

Code samples below:

**applicationContext-parent.xml**

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/views/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

View files are kept in parent under /src/main/resources/views

**applicationContext-child.xml**

```
<beans>
    // some other stuff
    <import resource="classpath:applicationContext-parent.xml" />
    // more stuff
</beans>
```

Comment: I don't see any issues doing it this way. Based on what you provided, this should work. Without a full example though, it's hard to say why it doesn't. What's the web.xml look like?

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider This is how i've got my current code and it returns a 404 not found on /views/index.jsp, i guess is because its looking in my child project for my views

Comment: In the project I'm working on, we resolved to using symlinks to make jsp files that are not in the src\main\webapp folder of the child project accessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer after much searching...

Its detailed here: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16603822/maven-parent-spring-webapp)

In essense...
"Have a look at the maven war plugin. This plugin allows what it calls overlays.

Overlays are used to share common resources across multiple web applications. The dependencies of a WAR project are collected in WEB-INF/lib, except for WAR artifacts which are overlayed on the WAR project itself."